# Columns borders not showing in fullcalendar agendaweek

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

The column borders aren't shown. I already deactivated all CSS but the fullcalendar one, but still the same. I even try just start full calendar as default but the same, the columns does not appear. :(

[image: No borders are shown]

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            alert(start);
        },  

        allDaySlot: false,
        lang:'es',
        slotEventOverlap:false,
        minTime: "09"+ ":00:00",
        maxTime: "20"+ ":00:00",
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        businessHours: {
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Thursday
            start: '08:00', // start time (8am)
            end: '17:00', // end time (5pm)
         },
         hiddenDays: [ 0, 6 ],  // Hide Sundays and Saturdays,

});
```

Comment: without seeing your code it's impossible to know for sure. But from your screenshot it appears you may have customised the CSS or used a different theme. That is likely to be the cause of your problem. Check for missing / conflicting CSS rules.

Comment: Thanks!, I thought so, I deactivated all css but the fullcalendar one, and it looks the same. I've updated the question, with my code.

Comment: Sorry but that can't be true. The default theme shows the column lines (check out the demos on the [fullCalendar home page](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos)). You must have missed something.

Comment: Using your code plus the default theme on fullCalendar 3.9, the column lines are shown. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1pzdnm40/ . Whatever your problem is, it's somewhere else in your page.

Comment: Thanks, mate, I'll check it out!